# How to use <Button-4> & <Button-5> to zoom in and out the image in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, ubuntu-14.04

```
def onWheel(event):
   d = event.delta
   if d < 0:
      amt=0.9
   else:
      amt=1.1
      canvas.scale(ALL, 200,200 , amt, amt)
canvas.bind("<Button-4>&<Button-5>", onWheel)
canvas.focus_set()
```

Here is my code. I run it in a tkinter window in ubuntu machine. But i can only zoom in the image. zoom out does not work.I want to zoom in & out the image by using button-4 & button-5

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the answer. Here is my code... I changed the above code as :

```
 from Tkinter import *
 root = Tk()

 Label(root, text='Zoom in & Zoom out using the Mouse Wheel' ,font('Times',12)).pack()

 canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
 canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
 canvas.create_rectangle(175,175,225,225,fill='blue')

 def zoomin(event):
   d = event.delta
   if d < 0:
      amt=0.9
   else:
      amt=1.1

   canvas.scale(ALL, 200,200 , amt,amt)
 canvas.bind("<Button-4>", zoomin)

 def zoomout(event):
   d = event.delta
   if d >0:
      amt=1.1
   else:
      amt=0.9
   canvas.scale(ALL, 200,200 , amt, amt)
 canvas.bind("<Button-5>", zoomout)
 canvas.focus_set()
 root.mainloop()
```